# How to set transaction timeout on Jetty JNDI Atomikos configuration

Tags: java, spring, jetty, jndi, atomikos

I am in the process of converting various Spring beans to JNDI lookups.  Currently I am using Jetty to test this.  I have configured the UserTransaction according to the Jetty documentation and it works:

```
<New id="tx" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Transaction">
    <Arg>
        <New class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

The problem with this configuration it that it does not set the transaction timeout like my Spring config did:

```
<bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
    <!-- Number of seconds before transaction timesout. -->
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="30" />
</bean>
```

I tried the following, but it didn't work...for some reason I ended up with TWO user transactions:

```
<New id="tx" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Transaction">
    <Arg>
        <New class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
            <Set name="transactionTimeout">30</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to configure the atomikos transaction manager through the `jta.properties` file within your jetty context.
For example, look at the following directory within your Jetty distribution (I'm using 6.1.24):

- /jetty-6.1.24/contexts/test-jndi.d/WEB-INF/classes

  - jta.properties

set the property called `com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout`, which is commented out in the default sample file.
Then make sure that you start your jetty container using the correctly configured context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you have any idea if this could be done without the `jta.properties` file?

Comment: I imagine it might be possible, but you'd have to set the values in the transaction manager as part of the server startup process.

Comment: Yes it is possible without the jta.properties. You can pass parameters to com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp.UserTransactionServiceImp class. If you use spring you can do it there or you can do it programmatically.